# Собрать все js-файлы в один в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Привет. Начинаю работать с Webpack и сейчас мой конфиг выглядит так:

```
'use strict';

var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/js/'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  }
};
```

В данном случае из папки `/dev/src/` берётся файл `app.js`, транспилируется в ES5 при помощи **babel-loader** и отправляется в папку `/assets/js/app.js`. Но у меня ещё есть папка `/dev/src/js-modules/`, в которой лежат различные js-модули, скачанные мной из различных источников. Мне в принципе не очень нравится идеология `require()` Node-модулей, поэтому я просто хочу собрать все js-файлы из папки `/dev/src/js-modules/` в один файл и отправить его по пути `/assets/js/modules.js`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

Можно просто указать еще одну entry point и в ней явно перечислить какие скрипты тебе нужны.

```
entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js",
    modules: ["./src/js-modules/script1", "./src/js-modules/script1"]
},
...
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/js/'),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
...}
```

Подробнее тут 
http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry

Comment: Этот конфинг просто прогонит через Webpack все файлы в `/assets/js/`, но не соберёт их все в один файл под одним названием.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin почему не соберет? Проверил у себя - содаются app.js и modules.js в которых бутстрап вебпака и обернутые в модули вебпака скрипты. Или вам нужно именно склеить скрипты "как есть"?

Comment: А нельзя просто пройтись по папке js-modules регуляркой и собрать все файлы? Например, /.js$/

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin webpack это прежде всего модульная система сборки. Т.е. в резульате все ваши скрипты станут модулями доступными к загрузке черезе require/import. Если это вам не нужно, можно использовать более простые технологии, например gulp. Там похожим образом описываются задача по сборке фронтенда. Там же можно просто склеить все скрипты в 1 файл, минифицировать его и тп.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin может уже видели, но на всякий случай оставлю ссылки здесь
про галп https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/gulp
про вебпак
https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack

Comment: видел, но меня интересует, чтобы работал и Babel и Gulp. Babel для транспиляции кода, а Gulp для минификации и сборки в один файл.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63205/discussion-between-chromigo-and-jamesjgoodwin).